# Combining Omniauth login (from one of several external ID providers) with our OAuth2-secured API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, oauth-2.0, omniauth

I'm refactoring a monolithic Rails app into a pure JSON API with a Backbone.js front end. Other smartphone app front-ends will be following in the near future, and the possibility of opening up the API to the public has been mooted around the office.

For that reason I thought I'd do the job properly the first time round and secure our REST API  with OAuth 2.0, so that every app built on it - including the ones we build in-house, is "just another OAuth client", which would also give us the usual niceties like rate limiting, key revocation and restriction on the resources that can be manipulated for free.

So far I've followed along with the [Railscasts episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/353-oauth-with-doorkeeper) on the Doorkeeper gem (warning, it's a pro episode) to secure our own API and register our user-facing web app as a client.

Now the interesting part - the original app allowed users to sign in through Facebook, Google, Twitter etc. through the Omniauth gem. As I understand it, OAuth is concerned with authorising clients, not user authentication, so we'll still need the OmniAuth flow we have already.

But:

- where should the "Omniauthing" controller live - in the API or the web client?
- how should the "Omniauth bit" to authenticate the user be connected to the "OAuth bit"?

**Update**: the client could either be just a Backbone app, or it could be a Backbone app twinned with a "thin Rails website wrapper" which has no DB of its own but mediates between the Backbone app and the API using ActiveResource. Which has the advantage of letting us deal with "a client that can keep a secret". In this scenario, the "Omniauthing" controller could live in the Rails client app if that's any use.

A [similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10456633/using-a-facebook-access-token-as-the-resource-owner-credentials-in-oauth2-0) discussed login only with Facebook, but while the answer was clear in saying there should only be one authorisation server - Facebook - it didn't say anything about feeding the outcome of user authentication to the resource server.

Comment: How did you approach this - I'm running into exactly this challenge now.